# MySQL Shell dump utility - maximum possible chunk size?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-shell

The documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html mentions that the min chunk size is 128kB. What is the maximum possible chunk size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max value is `innodb_buffer_pool_size / innodb_buffer_pool_instances` or some integral fraction of that.

But why bother changing the setting?  It should not make much difference.

Reference, and more discussion:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size